# Windows text font that has a glyph for Unicode character u2245 (i.e. approximately equal to)

Tags: windows-7, fonts, symbols

I'm looking for a font that has the glyph for Unicode character U+2245 ("approximately equal to", the equality sign with a tilde above it) for use on Windows 7. I have checked the main fonts and so far have not found it.

EDIT: Here's a picture of what happens with Cambria Math. You can see the selection-rectangle for the font at 12pt is very tall indeed, which is affecting line-spacing. The text is actually single-spaced.

[image]

Comment: Try asking here: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

`Arial Unicode MS` contains U+2245, U+2246 and U+2247.

and `Cambria Math`

Comment: Thanks. I see Cambria Math but Arial Unicode MS seems to have been available only on earlier versions of Windows. Weird behavior, however, with Cambria. I can see it on the Character Map utility, and select U+2245, and paste it into my document, but it's a mere speck on the page; the default font-size is only 2.5; when I select that one character in my document and increase its font size to 12, the document line-spacing gets screwy; the selection-rectangle around the symbol is about an inch tall even though the character itself is 12 pt. Cambria Math doesn't play well with Times New Roman.